# Building a simple USB notification light

Tags: led-strip, rgb

I successfully used an Arduino with the FastLED library to operate my [WS2812 Ring Light](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082SCYQM1). For my next project, I want to create a notification light for my PC.

Instead of using an arduino, I picked up a [USB 2.0 Male Adapter Dupont Extender Cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06Y5RKMT8) and connected the USB to my PC and connected the dupont wires to my other Ring Light. Now, I can successfully power the light, but I am absolutely clueless on how to get my Arduino sketch/C++ code to execute on it. All I want to do at this point is flicker the colors from Red to Green.

How can I transmit this color change on the white dupont wire?

Edit: I know this is no longer an arduino project, and I may need to use a different technology.

Comment: the cable has no capability to execute code

Comment: Can't I execute code on my PC, and feed the light instructions or something? I just want to make an external notification light for my PC.

Comment: @JeremiahDuane sure... with something in the middle. Like an arduino or any other usb microcontroller. Most pcs do not have user accessible gpio otherwise.

Comment: Blinkstick Pro is a USB device which can control many LED devices.  Maybe even this one due to the on-board chip, according to https://forums.blinkstick.com/t/ws2812b-support/170

Comment: @SethRobertson That looks promising! That might be what I end up doing... Although, it looks like it takes individual R, G, and B wires versus a single input wire? I'm not sure about that...

Comment: @Passerby Thanks! That makes sense.

Comment: gamers/posers  put addressable LEDs inside their PCs. some main-boards have a port for controlling LEDs -  might be on-topic in superuser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cable is just that... a cable. The ring light doesn't have a USB interface. The Arduino's role was to interface between USB and the light. You need to keep either some Arduino, or another microcontroller that has USB. You potentially could use a bare FTDI USB interface chip, since those can be used to "bit-bang" almost any data out their pins in the "bit blasting" mode (as opposed to the default serial UART mode). But either way, you'll be using some sort of an active, complex device as an interface between USB and the light.

Comment: Why can't I use my computer as the micro controller exactly? Like, an Arduino is just a simple computer right? I feel like I should be able to jus use my computer. The USB will always have to be plugged in anyway. 

 Thanks, I am a noob.

Comment: You're right, but there are different interfaces for sending information to devices, they are all similar in that they send a series of pulses one after another to represent bits, but there are differences in how those pulses look. Your PC motherboard has USB, maybe Serial or Firewire, it has I2C for communicating with devices on it's SMB (system management bus), but it does not have the hardware that knows how to send the exact series of pulses the LEDs will understand. You need hardware that can. Google "serial protocol comparison" to learn more

Comment: @JeremiahDuane The WS2812 has very precise timing requirements.  Easy to do with a microcontroller but nay impossible to do with a general purpose PC.

Comment: @JeremiahDuane The USB port on your computer is connected to a USB chip that only knows how to speak USB. The computer's CPU can tell the USB chip to do things like "send this USB packet". The USB chip doesn't understand "set the wire to +5V" because it's hard-wired for USB. Therefore you need an adapter chip, so you can send a USB packet to the adapter, the adapter chip receives the packet, and the adapter chip will set the wire to +5V.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks! That makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

A USB port can't speak WS2812, you need something else to convert something that USB can send into something that WS2812 understands.

It may be possible to port fastled's UART code to pc and use a serial port to drive the leds. else you could use an arduino as media converter.

Comment: That porting option sounds promising, though I don't know how you'd do that. I'm not against using an additional microcontroller to port the code either, but my PC has to be the main brain for this project, because the notification code has to read local PC files

Comment: you'd have to read it and figure out how to do the same with a uart on your pc... search for "FTDI WS2812"  someone else may have alredy done it,.

Comment: @JeremiahDuane Just use the additional microcontroller. You can use whatever protocol to talk to the microcontroller from the PC, and the microcontroller can then translate the colours into WS2812 protocol

Answer (score 3):

No, USB does not work like that. USB port is not GPIO like Arduino pins are. On an USB port you must use USB protocol for the PC operating system to be able to detect the device type and use the correct drivers for it so you can use it.

You need something between the PC and LEDs. Such as a microcontroller, which is what Arduinos are for example. That something must talk with PC using USB protocol with the LEDs using the WS2812 protocol.

That microcontroller must present itself as some useful device type to your PC over USB. For example, it makes no sense for it to be a mass storage device, a mouse or a camera, but it might make more sense for it to present itself as COM port for example.

And obviously, the program you write can do what it wants as long as it can open the COM port and send data to it, so that your microcontroller can receive it and set the LED colors - same thing you already did with your Arduino.

But something like this may already exist, so if you don't want to make it yourself, I bet there are USB RGB LED controllers already been made, and if you have a 'gaming' PC motherboard it may already contain a RGB LED controller onboard as many of them just have connectors to plug in addressable RGB LEDs directly.

Answer (score 2):

A microcontroller / Arduino is a really simple and cost-effective way to translate between USB and the WS2812 protocol.

While you could theoretically do it another way, it would be a lot harder and could end up costing more!

To make it tidy, you could get a very small Arduino-compatible board. Some are not much bigger than a USB plug; you could easily hide it behind your ring light.

Comment: I used one of those barely-more-than-USB-plug-sized Arduino-compatible boards (an Arduino Micro clone, I think?) and soldered a USB extension cable onto the USB pads so that my device would have a cable.

Answer (score 0):

There exist conversion cables, which are USB -connectable to a computer, and provide GPIO -style pins to external device; the conversion IC is hidden inside the USB type A plug.

Please see here for more information (manufactured by FTDI):
https://eu.mouser.com/c/wire-cable/cable-assemblies/usb-cables-ieee-1394-cables/?m=FTDI&series=TTL-232

for example, if you want the I/O logic be compatible with a 5V DC powered microcontroller, you might want to choose: TTL-232R-5V.

They have multiple versions available differing in features such as if you want to have I/O voltage levels compatible with 3.3V or 5V powered microcontroller and what type of connector (or none) you want at the other end of the cable (one end is USB type A to connect to your computer).

They may be available from other vendors too, but I selected the link to mouser, since they are a well known electronic component vendor with reasonable prices.

This cable could even be used as a microcontroller programmer (together with a suitable software running on a PC), but for this purpose, the cable is not optimal, although it can be made to work: Normally, the 6-pin connector has:

GND, +5V (powered by the computer's USB port), two GPIO inputs and two GPIO outputs (when running in mode that provides GPIO style pins), alternatively it can be run in RS-232 compatible serial communications mode, but the voltage levels are 0 / (almost) +5V instead of the +/- 9 to 12 V as it would be in a true serial port (like COM1 on a PC).

It can even be software configured to 3 outputs / only 1 input, but doing so may carry a risk: the 2 pins designed to be outputs have a (270 ohm ?) series resistor to prevent damage in case of accidental short circuit, but the pins designed to be inputs lack such protection, so if you use software to redefine one input as an additional output, then please be aware that accidentally short-circuiting the "makeshift output" (originally input) may very well damage the conversion IC built into this cable's USB connector.

If you can be careful enough to avoid accidental short-circuits, you could even have 4 independent outputs (with zero inputs left).

Or you could combine this cable with a microcontroller and have as many GPIOs as that microcontroller can provide, and command the microcontroller from a PC, and from FTDI's website ( https://ftdichip.com/ ) you should be able to find downloadable driver software to either enable a GPIO -compatible "bitbang" mode, or enable an emulation mode where the driver creates a virtual "COM11" -style device name on a PC, and with that, you communicate with a connected microcontroller as if it were a traditional (like COM1) com port on a PC.

Finally: a word of warning:

FTDI has been known to be aggressive to use extreme means of intellectual property right protection, such as making a driver update where the updated driver will work just fine with the original FTDI chip, but that will brick a third-party (possibly illegal) clone chip.

Because of this: purchase your cable (or other FTDI) product only from reputable resellers (or from FTDI itself). Otherwise you run the risk of getting a product that contains one of the illegally made clone chips, which the FTDI driver software may brick to render it (possibly permanently) unusable!

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP liked my comment, I will expand to a full answer.

One method to allow a standard multi-purpose computer (linux/windows PC) to achieve the necessary tight timing required by some LED strings, or simply to produce the correct voltage level on a pin that can have a wire attached to it is that you can use a product like [BlinkStick Pro](https://www.blinkstick.com/products/blinkstick-pro) which is a USB stick with some chip (ATTINY85-20PU) on it that takes commands from the host and controls the data line to have the desired effect.  It can also provide a limited (450 mA) amount of 5V power to actually power the LEDs--more power or different voltages requires external power (or finding a likely unused tap from inside the computer).

The BlinkStick Pro has five pins: +5V, Red, Green, Blue, and Ground.  This will, obviously, support LEDs that have separate RGB data lines, such as ones using three 5050 LEDs (though at least some of those use +12V, not +5V, so buyer beware--you might need a level shifter in addition to the higher voltage--see the BlinkStick Pro dev kit which appears to offer something like that).  However, for single-color LEDs (single 5050), or more complex LEDs that encode RGB using a single-wire protocol (like the 2812); you only need to use a single data pin (e.g. Red) to control the RGB on the entire string.  The other two pins (Blue/Green) can be disconnected.  Or, you can hook up additional LED strips to control them in parallel (instead of series: sticking them on the end of the first LED strip)--though the BlinkStick APIs appear to only support max 64 per data pin.  My understanding is that either should work (though voltage drop is real in long LED strings, certainly you would need to inject additional power at some point).

I was unable to immediately find a list of known supported LEDs for BlinkStick.  Certainly ws2812s are supported, as are SMD 5050s with the adapter I mentioned.  The NeoPixels and Ikea DIODERS (to drop some names mentioned on the BlinkStick website) are also supported.

There are lots of APIs for BlinkStick, and lots of people doing stuff, so hopefully you can get some help if you need it.

Disclaimer, I have no direct experience hacking the BlinkSticks--however I know someone who successfully used a BlinkStick Pro to solve a specific tactical problem I posed for a demonstration.